# MASM32 - "Unresolved external symbols" with underscores while linking

Tags: windows, assembly, masm32

I downloaded and extracted MASM32 + the SDK from the following website:  http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm

I then compiled and linked the following program using ml.exe and link.exe:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

; Windows libraries
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC
extrn ExitProcess@4 : PROC

option casemap:none ; Treat labels as case-sensitive

.DATA           ; Begin initialized data segment
  ProgramTitle db "Hello, puny humans!", 0 ; define byte
  DisplayText db "Wahahaha", 0

.CODE           ; Begin code segment
_main PROC

  push 0
  mov eax, offset ProgramTitle
  push eax
  push offset DisplayText
  push 0

  call MessageBoxA@16
  call ExitProcess@4

  ret
_main ENDP

END
```

Command-line:

```
ml /c test.asm
link /entry:_main /subsystem:windows test.obj
```

Output:

```
ml /c test.asm
    Assembling:  test.asm

link /entry:_main /subsystem:windows test.obj    
    test.obj : warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF
    test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MessageBoxA@16
    test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4
    test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Attempting to run a dumpbin on the .obj file:

```
Dump of file test.obj
test.obj : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored

    Summary
```

It seems strange to me that I am unable to link files utilizing the default functionality of MASM32 (ml.exe v. 6.14) and libraries that are included out-of-the-box.

Comment: If you're using MASM32 there's no need to use awkward syntax like `extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC` / `call MessageBoxA@16`. You could have just included user32.inc and done `invoke MessageBoxA NULL,ADDR DisplayText,ADDR ProgramTitle,NULL`

Answer (score 3):

The program must be compiled with the /coff option.  ml 6.14 is defaulting to OMF.  This is the cause of both dumpbin refusing the file (it only accepts COFF) and the linker warning "converting object format from OMF to COFF":

```
ml /c /coff test.asm
```

The dumpbin output reflects this:

```
File Type: COFF OBJECT

    Summary

        1D .data
        48 .drectve
        1A .text
```

And no output from the linker other than test.exe and Microsoft's copyright notices.

**Note:**

ML.EXE 6.14 is roughly 20 years old. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler))

Versions 7.0+ are bundled with the Visual C++ development environment.  Versions 8.0+ are under certain restrictions: ([masm32.com](http://www.masm32.com/history.htm))

> "Versions 7.0 and upwards are components of the Microsoft Visual C++
>   development environment and have also been made available in a number
>   of device development kits for successive versions of Microsoft
>   Windows. Version 8.0 and later have been available as free downloads
>   from Microsoft under a EULA that limits the use of the free versions
>   to developing code for Microsoft Operating Systems."

MASM 8.0 is available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654

Answer (score 1):

**EXTRA NOTE** with 6.14,

ml.exe will ignore the /coff option in this case (weird issue.)

```
ml test.asm /c /coff
```

ml.exe will take in account the /coff option.

```
ml /c /coff test.asm
```

Comment: Maybe that's because this is the syntax: `ML[ /options ] filelist [ /link linkoptions ]`